# Updating a template on separate template event

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I have a small meteor app.  Inside there are two templates, one with a selector, and one with simple text.  Anytime the selector is changed, I would like to get the second template to re-render.  I'm a bit new to this, so any help would be appreciated.

Main.html

```
<head>
  <title>btn-test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1>

  {{> selector}}
  {{> display}}
</body>


<template name="selector">
    <select id="carSelector">
        <option value="volvo" selected="selected">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</template>

<template name="display">
    {{selectorValue}}
</template>
```

Main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';


Template.selector.events({
  'change #carSelector': function(event){
    return event.currentTarget.value
  }
});

Template.display.helpers({
  "selectorValue": function(){
    return $('#carSelector').val();
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a reactive data source to store the selected value, I see you already install `ReactiveVar` package so let use it:

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var';

import './main.html';
const selectedValue  = new ReactiveVar('');

Template.selector.events({
  'change #carSelector': function(event){
    selectedValue.set(event.currentTarget.value);
  }
});

Template.display.helpers({
  "selectorValue": function(){
    return selectedValue.get();
  }

});
```

Comment: That works well.  I was also looking at a packages called Session, which allows you to set and get session variables.  These two methods seem very similar.  Are there any major differences between the two?  Is one preferred?  Thanks!

Comment: It depends on your situation, but do not use `Session` unless you have to because `Session` has global scope so it is very easy to mess it up